# Jeditable (asp.net C#)

Tags: html, jeditable

i'm using jeditable jquery with asp.net c#. I have a string which has to be edited, but when i edit it the whole html code come together. I want to edit only the title.

```
string initialHtml = "<P><B style='LINE-HEIGHT: 20px'><IMG class=iconEsquerda height=16 src='../images/arquivo_word.gif' width=16>&nbsp;<A href='5Pregão 40-13 Manutenção preventiva e corretiva em ventilador pulmonar - HAN - 12.0090.pdf' target=_blank><FONT color=#456db8>@@@ TITLE - EDIT ME!!!!@@@ </FONT></A></B></P>";
```

Comment: Where do you get this string?

Comment: this string comes from another website.

Comment: But how do you acquire it in code?  Can you acquire the more specific value you're looking for?  If you truly need to parse HTML then something like the HTMLAgilityPack might work for you.

Comment: could you explain me how do i use HTMLAgilityPack please?

Comment: The documentation is admittedly light, but there should be an example or two somewhere: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples  Google searches for more examples should reveal more as well.  Essentially you use it to parse HTML into more meaningful components (rather than trying to parse the HTML string manually).

Comment: Holy cow! i've tried to read but i i haven't understood a thing. I've also downloaded the dll and tried to import. Guess what? it did not work either